# Compromised printer?

Tags: security, malware, printer

Today the office printer produced three sheets with what seems to be random characters, and in the middle a string random1random2random3random4. This raised a red flag with us. Is this something to be worried about? We use the full stack of Meraki Go with Cisco Umbrella subscription activated. The printer model is Brother DCP-L5500DN, which is connected over ethernet directly to the router.

Here are the prints:
[Print 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJo4o.png)
[Print 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oryGy.png)
[Print 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOQNR.png)

Could this be an attack? Any advice on how to approach this?
Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that pretty much no one here will be aware of a compromised printer EVER in his career? Does that sort of answer the question? I definitely have not ever heard of something like this - more that some access TO the printer was compromised, but not the printer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that an employee ran an NMAP scan to discover some devices. Apparently this can cause an unexpected print (???). Below from the Meraki forum:

*Look what I found.  I am going to try this on some of my printers: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2237

Describe the bug
Aggressive option '-A' on printers produce unwanted print : binary blob with 'random1random2...'.
The printed payload 'random1random2...' is located here : "/usr/share/nmap/nselib/shortport.lua" line 261
To Reproduce
Run the following command on a printer device :
nmap -A X.X.X.34 -vvvvvvvvv -p 9100 --script-trace*

Kudos to Meraki Community member *Brandon S*

Comment: Second this. We had the same thing happen. It was related to a valid NMAP scan.